# Which BookFormatType for PDF?

Tags: pdf, schema.org, google-rich-snippets

I use the [`BookFormatType`](https://schema.org/BookFormatType) for [Google’s Book feature](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/book).

My structure is okay so far [according to the SDTT](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool#url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.usa-reisetipps.net%2Fe-book%2Fkompakt-ratgeber).

I offer:

- [`Paperback`](https://schema.org/Paperback)
- [`EBook`](https://schema.org/EBook)

But what should I use for a PDF? Or should I use a different Rich Snippet for the PDF?

Comment: Why wouldn’t the PDF be an ebook?

Comment: A eBook is not a pdf

Comment: Why not? Most ebook shops sell PDFs, most ebook readers can read PDF. See [E-book: Formats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E-book#Formats) and [Comparison of e-book formats: PDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_e-book_formats#Portable_Document_Format)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### PDFs are e-books

If the PDF contains a book, it is an e-book. (cf. Wikipedia: [E-book: Formats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E-book#Formats) and [Comparison of e-book formats: Portable Document Format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_e-book_formats#Portable_Document_Format)).

So for such a PDF, provide a [`Book`](https://schema.org/Book) with [`bookFormat`](https://schema.org/bookFormat) = [`https://schema.org/EBook`](https://schema.org/EBook).

If you want to provide the file type of the e-book, you can use the  [`fileFormat`](https://schema.org/fileFormat) property with a value of `application/pdf` ([IANA Media Types](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml)).

#### A book in multiple formats

As you offer different formats of a book (paperback, multiple e-books etc.), you should use one `Book` item that represents the work, and another `Book` item for each format.

You can link them with the [`workExample`](https://schema.org/workExample) property:

> Example/instance/realization/derivation of the concept of this creative work. eg. The paperback edition, first edition, or eBook.

#### JSON-LD example

```json
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org/",
  "@type": "Book",
  "name": "Gone with the Wind",
  "author": {
    "@type": "Person",
    "name": "Margaret Mitchell"
  },
  "workExample": [
    {
      "@type": "Book",
      "name": "Paperback of 'Gone with the Wind'",
      "bookFormat": "https://schema.org/Paperback"
    },
    {
      "@type": "Book",
      "name": "PDF of 'Gone with the Wind'",
      "bookFormat": "https://schema.org/EBook",
      "fileFormat": "application/pdf"
    },
    {
      "@type": "Book",
      "name": "EPUB of 'Gone with the Wind'",
      "bookFormat": "https://schema.org/EBook",
      "fileFormat": "application/epub+zip"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I haven't seen fileFormat. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the right solution:

```
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org/",
  "@type": "Book",
  "name": "Gone With the Wind",
  "encoding": {
    "@type": "MediaObject",
    "contentSize": "2.1 megabytes",
    "encodingFormat": "PDF"
  },
  "url": "http://www.ebookstodayfromthad.com/gonewiththewind"
}
```

Source [Github](https://github.com/schemaorg/schemaorg/issues/1887)